# Can I use a claw foot tub w/out attaching feet

Tags: bathroom, bathtub

recently bought a new claw foot tub. It hadn’t been installed yet, but already feel it is too big. I would like to use it WITHOUT attaching the feet. I would like to just have it sit on the floor on these four little stumps on the bottom that you can’t see. Can I do that?

Comment: So a picture would make all the difference to this question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Just because you're 4' tall doesn't make the tub too big. You probably *could* if you can get it to sit flat. But... *Do the feet sticking out at an angle of a claw foot bath tub help keep it from tipping over?*

Comment: You will probably find it very difficult to plumb if you set it directly on the ground. The space underneath is used for the drain. Also: does it really decrease the footprint at all?

Comment: @KMJ It decreases the *height*. If you plan the building for it, you can set a tub right into the floor - but that's very difficult to do as a remodel. Plumbing issue already raised in my answer.

Comment: I guess so, but if you're concerned about height a clawfoot is very much the wrong spot to start.

Answer (score 2):

Most such tubs *(you have not included pictures of the specific one as I write)* have a rounded bottom that would not sit well on the leg mounts alone. There will also be difficulty (or at least a larger hole in the floor required) with the usual arrangement of the drain plumbing.

One approach would be to "bed" the tub in plaster on the floor as is done for a good installation of built-in tubs with an apron in front of them. That will fully support the bottom, and is easily removed if/when the tub ever is. Some sort of frame to neatly contain it would be needed, since a clawfoot tub lacks the concealing apron.

Another would be to make 4 short built-up pillars, and then use plaster on top of them to ensure the tub is evenly supported.

To be clear, in both these methods the plaster is mixed and placed, and the tub is placed on the wet plaster before it sets, so that it hardens while conforming exactly to the gap between the tub and the floor, or pillars.

A reason not to forego the legs (other than the drain) is that it will make cleaning around and under the tub difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Check the manufacturer's literature. If there's no information in that literature and the manufacturer provides a technical hotline, then call it.

But if the manufacturer says "no" and you still want to do it? I imagine that your arrangement would result in smaller stresses in the tub than the ornamental feet, where the ornamental feet tend to spread outward instead of going straight down, introducing some bending into the legs. A problem with four legged structures, though, is that one leg may carry no weight because of imperfections in the leg lengths or foundation flatness. A solution to get some load back into one of these short, unloaded legs is to introduce some flexibility into the system. That flexibility could be in the legs, the tub body, or the foundation. It's possible that the feet were designed to introduce such flexibility, where your footless tub has effectively 3 legs instead of 4. I would add some flexibility by putting rubber disks beneath all four feet. I think that I have some table coasters made out of rubber that I might repurpose.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the "four little stumps" are; photo would be a huge help... If they're threaded-rid attachment points for the feet, I'd be inclined to cut a few chunks of board, drill holes in them, and use them as low replacement feet to spread the force a bit rather than resting on the rid directly.